# __bionic_open_tzdata_path: ANDROID_DATA not set!

Tags: shell, time-zones

When running commands like `date` or `ls -l` I always get a multiple repetition of the following lines to the standard error:

```
__bionic_open_tzdata_path: ANDROID_DATA not set!
__bionic_open_tzdata_path: ANDROID_ROOT not set!
```

I used to consider it acceptable, until I created a script running `date` in a loop, causing an awful endless stream of the same repeated lines.
I couldn't find any documentation about it, yet the problem seems to be common.
Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it seems that your terminal environment lacks two variables: `ANDROID_DATA` (usually `/data`) and `ANDROID_ROOT` (`/system`). Try to assign these values to said variables and run the commands again.

Comment: Thank you @DeathMaskSalesman, I've just realised that the problem occurs only in ssh shell, not in AndroidTerminalEmulator.  I was looking for an answer far away while the answer was just in front of my eyes.

Answer (score 6):

For **ssh** users, following up on @Death Mask Salesman's comment. sshd allows setting up ENV via proper config (from `man --pager='less -p ^ENVIRONMENT' ssh`):

> [...] Additionally, ssh reads ~/.ssh/environment, and adds lines of the format “VARNAME=value” to the environment if the
>        file exists and users are allowed to change their environment.  For more information, see the PermitUserEnvironment
>        option in sshd_config(5).

However I couldn't succeed to set it up on my phone (Sony Xperia "Tsubasa" / LineageOS 14.1). Thus I resorted to adding in `/etc/bash/bashrc`:

```
export ANDROID_DATA=/data ANDROID_ROOT=/system
```

then logging in...

```
$ ssh root@... -t bash
tsubasa / # env | grep ANDROID_
ANDROID_DATA=/data
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution, fixing the issues that sphakka had in his answer.

Create these 2 files:

```
/data/ssh/root/.ssh/environment
/data/ssh/shell/.ssh/environment
```

With the following content:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/vendor/lib:/system/lib
PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/system/sbin:/sbin/.magisk/modules/ssh/usr/bin
ANDROID_DATA=/data
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
```

You might need to set permissions for these 2 files `chmod 755 environment`

Very important: Enable **PermitUserEnvironment yes** in `/data/ssh/sshd_config`

Restart the sshd with `/sbin/.magisk/modules/ssh/opensshd.init restart`